Word crashes after Office Update on May/June 2024
Since the Word update to version 2405/2406 on May/June, we have different problems with Word.Interop.
We have a VSTO addin developed with c# to interoperate with Word, in which we use the Interop.Word.Document.ContentControlOnExit event to manage behaviors, one of them sets Interop.Range.HighlightColorIndex, this causes a Word crash in these versions, in 2404 it works.
We also have this problem: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/after-installing-word-version-2405-on-may-30-2024/e8e704ea-96ce-4380-bc6a-30e3911c95b5
Does anyone have a workaround for this problem? We have rolled back to version 2404 to avoid complaints.

You will have to debug your add-in

Cant debug, our Addin crash in >=2405 setting value in Interop.Range.HighlightColorIndex, and no crash in 2404. We extract a mini dmp and the callstack is unmanaged code of interop. It seems that we are in the exit of a contentcontrol and the sethighlight causes another exit and an internal interop stackoverflow occurs, but it is not a certainty since we cannot debug unmanaged code.

If you can’t debug as the author of the add-on then we have no way of helping. Something has changed, the changes between 2404 through 2406 are most documented. I would had code to diagnose the problem.

From the citation you supplied, it appears MS has removed or broken some features of Word with that update.
You have two choices:

Revert to an older Word version, if feasible, or
Revise your C# code.

Stop using Interop.Range.HighlightColorIndex, substituting Range.Find, or other object.
Extend exception handling around use of Interop.Range.HighlightColorIndex. Add a try/catch block to record what arguments or return value cause the issue.



Note also, stated in your citation, "MS recommends that we move from object model to XML approach." Does that affect your C# extension installation?

@DrMoishe Pippik  We have currently rolled back production to version 2404, and if they do not solve this or there is some alternative that we don't know about... we will have no choice and we will move to remove this functionality from the user. We cannot catch Interop.Range.HighlightColorIndex, this causes an internal interop crash, word proccess finalize, the code does not reach the catch. thank you!

@DrMoishe Pippik for the problem with de options menu, we found the microsoft problem and adjust code to solve their problems, port options menu to XML model also solve the problem, we currently only have problems with highlightcolor
